# MySql create a table with 600 columns

Tags: mysql

Trying to find the easiest way to create 600 columns into a table in mysql without having to type in each one.

Eventually, Im also going to have to figure out a way to update records to this, also without having to type in each column name to insert data. Any tips with be greatly appreciated!

The column names are as follows:

```
check_1
check_1_status
check_1_comment
check_2
check_2_status
check_2_comment
...
etc.
...
check_200
check_200_status
check_200_comment
```

Comment: You should look into database normalization. Your 600 columns in one table might be better served by 200 rows in 3 tables.

Comment: or .... normalize to use a table with 5 columns (check, status, comment plus a foreign key and the primary key)

Comment: apropos limits https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/column-count-limit.html#:~:text=The%20internal%20representation%20of%20a,the%20rest%20of%20the%20row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely **NOT** a good idea for a single table to own 600 columns, not to mention there is a limit for row size. The following is a demonstration of how we can do it in a stored procedure.

```
delimiter //

create procedure create_table(in num int)
begin
declare id int default 2;

drop table if exists test;
create table test(check_1 char(1), check_1_status char(1), check_1_comment char(1));

while id<=num do
set @stmt=concat('alter table test add check_',id,' char(1), add check_',
id,'_status char(1), add check_',id,'_comment char(1);');

prepare stmt from @stmt;
execute stmt;


set id=id+1;

end while;
deallocate prepare stmt;

end//

delimiter ;

-- now let's create a table with the max column_id set to 200
call create_table(200);
desc test;
-- result with the majority omitted:
| check_195         | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_195_status  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_195_comment | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_196         | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_196_status  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_196_comment | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_197         | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_197_status  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_197_comment | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_198         | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_198_status  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_198_comment | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_199         | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_199_status  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_199_comment | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_200         | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_200_status  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| check_200_comment | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
600 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

Now you might wonder why the data type for each column is set with extreme conciseness. The reason for doing so is because there is a limit on row size. As to demonstrate it, let's change the check_id_comment to `text` type, and run the procedure again.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists create_table//
create procedure create_table(in num int)
begin
declare id int default 2;

drop table if exists test;
create table test(check_1 char(1), check_1_status char(1), check_1_comment text);

while id<=num do
set @stmt=concat('alter table test add check_',id,' char(1), add check_',
id,'_status char(1), add check_',id,'_comment text;');

prepare stmt from @stmt;
execute stmt;


set id=id+1;

end while;
deallocate prepare stmt;

end//

delimiter ;
```

Now let's run the new procedure, which has its check_id_comment set to `text` type.

```
call create_table(200);
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

As denoted above in the error message, by replacing `char(1)` with `text` ,the row size limit has been reached.